# Call repository method into a map

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I'm new to webflow and I'm stuck... I think I'm doing it wrong.
In my service i have this method :

```
public Mono<Void> createThings(Flux<Thing> things) {
return things
        .map(mapper::toEntity)
        .map(ThingEntity::onCreate)
        .map(thingEntity -> {

            // set the date
            if (thingEntity.getSomething() != null &&
                    thingEntity.getSomething().equals("truc")) {
                thingEntity.setDateTruc(LocalDate.now());
            }
            // if exists, set others dates
            repository
                    .existsByNumberThing(thingEntity.getNumberThing())
                    .map(exists -> {
                        thingEntity.setDate1(Boolean.TRUE.equals(exists)?LocalDateTime.now():null);
                        thingEntity.setDate2(Boolean.TRUE.equals(exists)?null:LocalDateTime.now());
                        return thingEntity;
                    });

            return thingEntity;
        })
        .flatMap(repository::save)
        .doOnError(error -> log.error("Error : ", error))
        .then(Mono.empty());
```

}

Dates date1 and date2 have not changed ...
I tried to use a flatMap, to return a Mono but errors in repository.save() :

> java: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) R
> (argument mismatch; invalid method reference
> method save in interface

I don't know how to do it, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found my problem ... I've added a flatmap and a private method that handles this code.

```
public Mono<Void> createThings(Flux<Thing> things) {
  return things
    .map(mapper::toEntity)
    .map(ThingEntity::onCreate)
    .map(thingEntity -> {

        // set the date
        if (thingEntity.getSomething() != null &&
                thingEntity.getSomething().equals("truc")) {
            thingEntity.setDateTruc(LocalDate.now());
        }

        return thingEntity;
    })
    .flatMap(this::myPrivateMethod)
    .flatMap(repository::save)
    .doOnError(error -> log.error("Error : ", error))
    .then(Mono.empty());
```